# Doctrine cache unrecognized options error

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using the following options in order to activate the cache for doctrine in Symfony2:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        ...
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
> Unrecognized options "metadata_cache_driver, query_cache_driver,
> result_cache_driver" under "doctrine.orm"

I'm using the following versions:

> doctrine/cache: v1.4.1
>
> doctrine/common: v2.5.0
>
> doctrine/dbal: v2.4.4
>
> symfony/symfony: v2.6.11

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have more than one entry in ``entity_managers`` section?

Comment: I have two entity managers defined.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have more than one Entity Manager configured under `entity_managers` section of your `config.yml` then you need to configure these options separately for each Entity Manager:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                ...
                metadata_cache_driver: apc
                query_cache_driver: apc
                result_cache_driver: apc
            another_entity_manager:
                ...
                metadata_cache_driver: apc
                query_cache_driver: apc
                result_cache_driver: apc
```

Comment: You saved my ass.!! I couldn't do cache:warmup for Symfony because of that for the last 2 hours trying to understand why Symfony is looking for a database under root user when it's not what I requested.. because it overrided the setted config